# Searching for specific characters within a string using a for loop to check time format in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, substring

I'm writing a script where a user has to put in a time. The issue I'm running into is that the user can enter anything and batch script will accept it. My idea to check for this was to extract where the colon should be in the time inputted and check if it's there with this:

```
SET check=%utime:2,1%
IF %check%==: [continue with script]
```

So that it'd skip the first two characters in say 01:00 and extract the semi colon, set it to `check` and then compare `check` to see if it was a colon or not. This works great but then I realized that a user could input anything with a colon in the third space and get past. For a first step my idea to check for this was to have a `FOR` loop check all the five possible spaces to see if they were empty or not with this code:

```
SET conf=1
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
echo %%i
SET check=%utime:%%i,1%
IF [%check%] == [] SET conf=0
)
```

`conf` would be a true or false variable (0 or 1) that I could then evaluate with an `IF` statement to then see if it's a valid format. But what ended up happening is that `conf` was set to 0 but it was not correctly checking the characters within the `time` variable. Leaving the echo on I could see that `check` was not correctly being set meaning `conf` was always set to 0 no matter what was inputted from the user. Here is the code in question in context just in case (This portion is only meant to check for 5 characters being present):

```
:Start
SET /p utime=Please insert the time (hh:mm):
CALL :CheckTime
IF conf EQU 1 goto :Valid
ECHO Please enter a valid time!
GOTO :Start

:Valid
ECHO Thank you for entering a valid time!
PAUSE
EXIT

:CheckTime
SET conf=1
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
echo %%i
SET check=%utime:%%i,1%
IF [%check%] == [] SET conf=0
)
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit different approach then Compo.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\14\SO_50860883.cmd
@Echo off
:Start
Set "MyTime="
SET /p MyTime=Please insert the time (hh:mm):
If not defined MYTime Exit /B 0
CALL :CheckTime "%MyTime%"|| (ECHO Please enter a valid time! &GOTO :Start)

ECHO Thank you for entering a valid time %MyTime% !
ECHO=
goto :Start

:CheckTime passed value not a fixed var
Echo=%~1|Findstr "^[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ^2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$" 2>&1>Nul || Exit /B 1
```

To not allow the input of a single digit hour change the last line to :

```
Echo=%~1|Findstr "^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ^2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$" 2>&1>Nul || Exit /B 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This covers everything I need. Can you tell me what the `^` and `$` do in that last line? It seems to catch anything afterwards or before the string but I don't want to assume something and have it not be right.

Comment: Findstr works by default (or expressed with /R) with Regular expressions. in a RegEx the `^` anchors at the begin and the `$` at the end. I included these to avoid trailing or leading other chars. I allow also to enter the our as a single digit as a valid exception.

Comment: 9:21 isn't a valid time ;-)

Comment: @Compo you are right, should have changed that to include a leading zero then.

Comment: So after messing around with it and editing to implement into my own use, I noticed that `"` always goes through no matter what. If it's by itself or in a string it always makes it go through, do you guys know why this is or how I can stop it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't verify this, what entries pass without being rejected?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `FindStr` would be suitable:

```bat
:Start
Set "uTime="
Set /P "uTime=Please insert the time (hh:mm): "
Set "uTime=%uTime:~,5%"
If Not Defined uTime GoTo :Start
Echo %uTime% |FindStr /R "[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] 2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]">Nul||GoTo :Start
Echo Thank you for entering a valid time!
Pause
```

Comment: This works great! The only issue I come across is it doesn't seem to check for characters after the time e.g. 12:00qwer goes through fine. Is there a way I can check if the character following the time is blank? I tried using just empty brackets but it didn't work.

Comment: 24:59 isn't a valid time ;-)

Comment: @Pitdroid, I have included an additional line to restrict the variable to the first five characters entered, if they use `12:00qwer`, the variable will be set to `12:00`, if they enter `qwer12:00` it will not pass as valid.